# How much repackaging and restarting do I need to do for JIRA plugin development?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Just getting started learning how to develop plugins for JIRA, and I was following this tutorial: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+Custom+Field+Type which is very well written, but the one thing I"m not clear on is how much of the packaging and deployment commands I have to re-run each time I iterate on my design?

I have a pretty fast box, but between the `atlas-mvn eclipse:eclipse` command, the `atlas-create-jira-plugin-module` command and the `atlas-run` command, it feels like I'm doing some old school heavy compiling on each iteration.  Like the 'run get a coffee while you wait' kind of compiling. Are any of those steps unnecessary on a local re-deploy after code update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `atlas-run` command downloads an entire jira server application (a bundled tomcat) in your current folder and starts it up.

You don't have to run `atlas-mvn eclipse:eclipse` every time you make a change to your code. That's just in the beginning when constructing the eclipse plugin.

I would suggest the following:

**STEP 1**

Download and install a regular Jira installation locally. (the exact version you need, if not the latest one)

**STEP 2**

Package (compile your plugin) by going into the project folder and running `atlas-mvn clean package`.

This will compile your plugin jar file to the target folder.

**STEP 3 - installing the plugin**

Once you have your plugin jar file, there are 2 ways to install / deploy it, depending on what type of plugin it is: **plugins1** or **plugins2**

(Here's the difference the two types: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA043/Differences+between+Plugins1+and+Plugins2)

**plugins1:**
A plugin of this type gets installed in the `WEB-INF/lib` of your application, and starts up along with the Jira tomcat server.
Of course, this means that every time you re-deploy it, you have to shut down Jira, copy your jar there, and start it up again.

**plugins2:**
Most of the plugins are of this type.
This kind of plugin can be installed while Jira is started from the "add-ons" administration menu. (so you don't have to shut down Jira everytime you update the code)

This way of deployment will save you a lot of time.